# Export Adobe xd to React/HTML

Tags: plugins, export, adobe

I am trying to export Adobe xd to React or html/css using fireblade xd plugin , but it gives me error like "Error: Syntax error: unexpected token H in json at position 0"
could you please help me ??
i am trying since last few days.. looking for your support !! Help Me ?? [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg8Fa.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced similar error. I found that I was making a @TextInput group of elements which did not hold all the required elements with the correct attributes.

Here an example of what I did wrong:

```
- username @TextInput
  --  label_username #value           (element is hidden)
  --  box_username #container         (element is visible)
```

And here an example of what should be done:

```
- username @TextInput
  --  label_username #placeholder     (element is visible)
  --  label_username #value           (element is hidden)
  --  box_username #container         (element is visible)
```

If your issue persists, consult with the documentation [here](https://docs.fireblade.io/tutorial/form-elements).

Answer (score 0):

You (probably) have some non-standard text a the beginning of a file with `.json` extension.

If you can find it, [ensure that the format](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) is something similar to

```
[
  {
    "someProperty": {
      "subProperty": "some text value"
    }
  },
  {
  ...
  ..
  ....
]
```

The issue seems to be that there's some text outside of the parenthesis, but that is not allowed from the JSON format specification.